# Confirmation link on registration FOS UserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to use the register confirmation provide by FOS User Bundle but the email I receive contains only :

> registration.email.message

There's no link which I can click on in order to activate my account freshly created. Did I miss something during the configuration ?

Btw, I'm using Symfony 3.x and working with devmail for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the translator is enabled in your config.yml (http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#translations) and the return of `php bin/console debug:translation en FOSUserBundle` contains the `registration.email.message` id.
Remember that you need to clear the cache `php bin/console cache:clear` after installing FOSUserBundle.

Also note that if you have a custom email template and wish to use the FOSUserBundle translations you must have this `{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}` on it´s first line, just like the default one https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Registration/email.txt.twig.

Comment: I am using the email template provide by FOSUser and it already contains the line you mentioned

Comment: @Maxime The translator is enabled in your config.yml (http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#translations)?  Have you cleared the cache `php bin/console cache:clear` after installing FOSUserBundle? What does this command returns to you `php bin/console debug:translation en FOSUserBundle`? Try the same command using your locale if not en.

Comment: Problem solved ! It was the translator, thanks for your help